# Html.BeginCollectionItem only nested proeprties are null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, null, nested

I use Html.BeginCollectionItem helper for getting an edited variable length list. It works for non-nested properties (string Member.Info, int Member.MotherID, etc.) but **all nested ones are null** (Mother Member.Mother, etc.)...

Member class:

```
 public class Member : Person
 {
    [Key] 
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public int MotherID { get; set; }

    public virtual Mother Mother { get; set; }
 }
```

Nested Mother class:

```
 public class Mother : Person
 {
    [Key]
    public int MotherID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Member> Children { get; set; }

    public Mother()
    {
        Children = new List<Member>();
    }
}
```

Controller snippet:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GoSend(IEnumerable<Member> me) // Mother in 'me' is null
 {...}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Directory_MVC.Models.Member>
 ...
 @using (Html.BeginForm("GoSend", "Members", FormMethod.Post))
 {
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("EditorRow", item);       
    }
 }
```

EditorRow.cshtml:

```
 @model Directory_MVC.Models.Member
 ...
 @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("me"))
 {
      @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Info)
      @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MotherID)
      @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Mother)
      @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Mother.Email)
 }
```

Generated HTML for that broken Mother input is:

```
 <input id="me_88c3c30f-3aa7-4729-9879-368f01073080__Mother" name="me[88c3c30f-3aa7-4729-9879-368f01073080].Mother" type="hidden" value="System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Mother_5D771F511FE55BBA8F7C7D21A0054616D2EB9278EDCA1D59DFDCB1B68EA45920" />
```

Generated HTML for working MotherID input is:

```
 <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MotherID must be a number." data-val-required="The MotherID field is required." id="me_88c3c30f-3aa7-4729-9879-368f01073080__MotherID" name="me[88c3c30f-3aa7-4729-9879-368f01073080].MotherID" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

What am I doing wrong? **Is it even possible to serialize that Mother object** and retrieve it in that Controller via the Html.BeginCollectionItem?

Comment: Of course, I can retrieve the referenced data (such as Mother) by their IDs from the context... but I'm wondering if there is any more elegant solution.